# Denoting keyboard shortcuts in Stack Exchange posts

Tags: support, faq, kbd

What is the recommended method/syntax for denoting keyboard shortcuts in Stack Exchange questions and answers?

For example, how would you write the following in a less verbose manner?

- Press ctrl, and press either the minus key or the equals key
- Ctrl or cmd, and lowercase c
- Ctrl, alt and a, then ctrl and uppercase l
- Hold ctrl or cmd while scrolling with the mouse wheel

*(Well, the last one isn't strictly a keyboard shortcut)*

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 75):

Note that you can now do this using the `<kbd>` tag.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Obviously you have to watch your line spacing due to the additional height of the line.

Comment: It almost seems unfair that you get to implement a feature in order to provide the best answer to certain questions. :)

Comment: Why isn't this answer marked as correct?

Comment: These don't work in comments unfortunately

Comment: For comments you can simply use `Ctrl` + `-`

Answer (score 9):

I’d say we do it just like it’s done all over the world since the beginning of time.

- Ctrl-Minus/=
- Ctrl-c
- Ctrl-a Ctrl-L

Comment: "we do it just like it’s done all over the world since the beginning of time"? With sticks and mud?

Comment: Ancient writing techniques included the wedge, the reed stylus, and bone/metal styli: https://cdli.ox.ac.uk/wiki/doku.php?id=cuneiform_writing_techniques . For those of us in modern times, we can search the internet for keyboards with cuneiform keycaps or use Unicode renderings.

Comment: You guys are very anthropocentric, at the beginning there was energy, lots of it, that's what scientists and religious people said alike.

Answer (score 9):

I'd say we do it just like it is done all over the world since the beginning of time:

- `C--` or `C-=`
- `C-c`
- `C-a C-L`
- `C-x M-c M-butterfly`

Comment: Ah, good old xkcd :-D

Comment: This one I did not get..;(